# Not working post request with C#

Tags: c#, php, webrequest

I need to write simple registration form and can't get it working, also tried KeyValuePair with no luck.

C#:

```
        HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();            
        Dictionary<string, string> keys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        keys.Add("user", "testuser");
        keys.Add("email", "woohoo@ch.com");
        keys.Add("pass", "1q23");
        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keys);
        string url = "http://web.address/register.php";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Include config
require_once 'config/db.php';
$sql = new db();
$conn = $sql->connect();

$user = isset($_GET['user']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['user']) :  "";
$email = isset($_GET['email']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['email']) :  "";
$pass = isset($_GET['pass']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['pass']) :  "";


if(!empty($user) && !empty($email) && !empty($pass))
{
    $qur = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into users (username, email, first_name, last_name, password, creation_date) values ('". $user ."', '". $email ."', 'workee', 'worker', '". crypt($pass, '$6$rounds=5000$Ws7S0ftware3v3r$') ."', '". time() ."');");
}
@mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

But it does work straight from link:

```
http://web.address/register.php?user=testuser&pass=1q23&email=woohoo@ch.com
```

Comment: Your PHP code specifically is reading *GET* values, not *POST* which you are using from C#. Also learn immediately to use parameters. Your database code is open to SQL injections.

Comment: You are POSTing the data while your PHP code is GETing the data...

Comment: yea, my bad. That fixed the problem! Thanks!

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Anyone calling the web URL could include values which could steal, corrupt or destroy your data. Learn to use parameterised queries to make your database safer, there are hundreds of examples online. Joining strings together like that is extremely dangerous. Escaping the strings can help but it is it not the intended purpose of those functions to protect against injection attacks, and so it does not adequately defend you. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for an explanation and some examples of how to write queries safely using mysqli.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for advise